# Share session (asp->asp.net) security

Tags: asp.net, security, session, asp-classic

I need to share session in order to pass data from `asp` page to `aspx`. The solutions I've found:

• Pass data through hidden form [(link)](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/articles/20021207.asp)
• Pass data through database [(link)](http://www.asp101.com/articles/sidney/sharingsessionstate/default.asp)

I've tried method with form and it worked fine (after some modification). Now I'm trying method with database. First method is easier imho, so I wonder if the second method is more secure (and preferable) than the first one?
And what potential problems exist with these methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first solution is definitely less secure since you're sending session data to the client and then receiving it back. That means that it's possible for someone on the client side to modify the data they post back to your page. This removes one of the best things about sessions, that only the programmer controls what's in them. In a way, the first method is similar to using cookies. As for the second method, it may be more difficult but I would definitely recommend it over the first.

Comment: *That means that it's possible for someone on the client side to modify the data they post back to your page* - unless you're using [secure cookies](http://www.cse.msu.edu/~alexliu/publications/Cookie/cookie.pdf).

Comment: @Zed: I'm not talking about cookies there. I'm talking about posted form data. Thanks for posting that though, I'm going to give it a read. :)

Comment: The paper is somewhat cookie-centric but those ideas are applicable for every client-side session data that you want to be temper-proof.

Comment: @Zed- True, I hadn't read it yet. :) Though personally, I'd still prefer to keep things server-side if at all possible.

Answer (score 1):

If the session is encrypted I think you will fine. ASP.NET has the option of storing the session in a database and URL querystring to get around users not having cookies enabled. Your solutions sound similiar.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft outlines a method to share session state between ASP classic and ASP.NET using SQL Server to store the session here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479313.aspx